# Why is Python logging framework losing messages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-requests, error-logging

I have a Python 3.4 application that uses logging extensively. I have two `FileHandler`s and a `StreamHandler` registered. Everything works as expected except that sometimes, and it seems to happen after the `requests` library throws an exception, the log files lose all the accumulated messages and start with new messages. I'm assuming that for some reason the `FileHandler`s reopened the files with `mode='w'`, but I don't understand why. Any ideas?

The main program sets up the loggers as follows:

```
# Set up root logger - two handlers logging to files
fh_debug = logging.FileHandler('Syncer.debug', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
fh_debug.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh_log = logging.FileHandler('Syncer.log', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
fh_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh_formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)
fh_debug.setFormatter(fh_formatter)
fh_log.setFormatter(fh_formatter)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(fh_debug)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(fh_log)

# Add console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
ch_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(ch_formatter)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(ch)

# Need to set the logging level of the logger as well as the handlers
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Set up the logger for this module
logger = logging.getLogger("Syncer")

logger.debug('Logger started.')
```

The modules simply contain:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Comment: Does something happen in that exception handler like maybe importing the main file for some other purpose? You could keep a rolling set of files (Syncer.debug.0, Syncer.debug.1, etc...) so that you have more history.

Comment: I haven't create an exception handler. A quick fix is to open the files with mode='a'. But it would be nice to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you chose the wrong `mode` for your `FileHandler`.

The default mode of `FileHandler` is `a` which means appends new lines to the log file.

```py
class logging.FileHandler(filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=False)
```

You modified the default mode to `w` which truncate file to zero length or create a new file for writing. That's why you lost all accumulated messages.

**Change it to `mode='a'` or just delete `mode='w'` and then your logger will work.**

Read the [official python docs here](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Ejdg001/local-archive/python-3.4-reference/library/logging.handlers.html)

Comment: I was fully expecting the log files to be truncated when the application was started. What I didn't expect was that part way through a single run of the program the log file would "spontaneously" truncate. Any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

This happens on an exception that would cause Python to exit, because the `logging` module gets (partially) shutdown, causing the log file to be closed, but then `requests` tries to log something, so the logger reopens the log file - unfortunately, truncating it.

From [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.0/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1181):

```
class FileHandler(StreamHandler):
    # [...]

    def close(self):
         # [...]
         self.stream = None
         # [...]

    def _open(self):
        return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding,
                    errors=self.errors)

    def emit(self, record):
        if self.stream is None:
            self.stream = self._open()
        StreamHandler.emit(self, record)
```

I think the simplest workaround is to truncate the logfile on program start and tell `logging` to open the file in append mode:

```
open('Syncer.debug', mode='w').close() # truncate
fh_debug = logging.FileHandler('Syncer.debug', mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
fh_debug.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
open('Syncer.log', mode='w').close() # truncate
fh_log = logging.FileHandler('Syncer.log', mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
fh_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved as part of this [commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/96cf5a63d2dbadaebf236362b4c7c09c51fda55c) which "fixed log truncation on logging shutdown".